# HTTP error occurred during file upload (404: File not found) when uploading images to CKEditor with KCFinder

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, http-status-code-404, kcfinder

I've installed ckeditor and kcfinder in my /public directory. 
Despite having added to /public/ckeditor/config.js:

```
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';

config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
```

and enabled KCFinder in /public/kcfinder/config.php

```
'disabled' => false,
'uploadURL' => "/uploads",
// The uploads directory is inside /public
```

I got an error trying to upload images to CKEditor.

[HTTP error occurred during file upload (404: File not found).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4sHL.png)

I've noticed some errors in my console

```
[CKEDITOR] Error code: cloudservices-no-token-url.
[CKEDITOR] Error code: cloudservices-no-upload-url.
```

Comment: You can try laravel filemanager

Comment: Is filemanager intergrate-able with CKEditor?

Comment: yes you can use in any editor